# Вывод скопированной строки/столбца матрицы

Tags: c#, winforms, матрицы, вывод

Требуется вывести строку и столбец(номера задаются пользователем) из матрицы, матрицу для удобства я разбил на два массива, т.к. вывод осуществляется по отдельности: строка - массив X, столбец - массив Y. Каким образом можно вывести строку и столбец матрицы? Код ниже:

```
private void Calc_B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[,] m = new int[DGV_A.RowCount, DGV_A.ColumnCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < DGV_A.RowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < DGV_A.ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            m[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(DGV_A[j, i].Value);
        }
    }

    int[] x = new int[DGV_A.RowCount];
    int[] y = new int[DGV_A.ColumnCount];
    
    int p1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); // Ввод числа для получения строки p
    int q1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);  // Ввод числа для получения столбца q

    for (int i = 0; i < DGV_A.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        x[i] = Convert.ToInt32(DGV_A[i, p1].Value);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < DGV_A.ColumnCount; j++)
    {
        y[j] = Convert.ToInt32(DGV_A[q1, j].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: @Bulson, Каким образом можно вывести строку и столбец матрицы?

Comment: А куда выводить нужно? Если в текстбокс, то используйте [String.Join()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", x))`

Comment: @aepot, Вывод в компонент DataGridView

Comment: как строку или столбец? x в одну таблицу, y в другую? или оба в одну? чем должны быть заполнены остальные ячейки?

Comment: @aepot, матрица заполняется, пользователь вводит номер строки и столбца, потом должен быть вывод нужной строки (в отдельную таблицу) и так же столбца

Comment: @aepot, нужно получить массив X = {xj}, j =1...m, равный p-ой строке матрицы A = {aij} и массив Y = {yi}, i =1...n, равный q-му столбцу матрицы A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> матрица заполняется, пользователь вводит номер строки и столбца, потом должен быть вывод нужной строки (в отдельную таблицу) и так же столбца

Просто скопировать ячейки пробовали?

```csharp
for (int i = 0; i < DGV_A.RowCount; i++)
{
    DGV_B[i, p1].Value = DGV_A[i, p1].Value;
}

for (int j = 0; j < DGV_A.ColumnCount; j++)
{
    DGV_B[q1, j].Value = DGV_A[q1, j].Value;
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, работает, но в верхней части матрицы - 1 строка, 2й столбец выводится число, которого НЕ должно быть

Comment: @Orion Условия циклов перепроверьте, у вас везде `ColumnCount`. Ну и смотрите остальной код, из ниоткуда там ничего не возмется.

Comment: дьявол кроется в деталях, в вашем ответе в строке : DGV_B[q1, j].Value = DGV_A[q1, j].Value; - q1 стоит на месте j в первых скобках, вот и нашёл ошибку

Comment: @Orion ничего не понял, поменять местами надо было чтоли? ну ок.

Comment: но и это ещё не всё, финальный вид:             for (int i = 0; i < DGV_A.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                DGV_X[i, p1].Value = DGV_A[i, p1].Value;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < DGV_A.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                DGV_X[j, q1].Value = DGV_A[j, q1].Value;
            }

Comment: @Orion ну, вы копируете 2 строки, а где столбцы то?

Comment: Я сейчас полностью задание закончу и сброшу код

Comment: сделано, последняя версия загружена